# Initial Form Django não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: python, django, formulário, post, get

Bom eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em django e estou tentando usar jquery com django para fazer uma requisição ao ViaCep para consultar o cep que a pessoa digitou e saiu do foco do campo que estava digitando.

essa é a minha view.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def cadastro_empresa(request):
    
    cep = request.GET.get('cep')

    try:
        resposta = cep_consulta(cep)
        logradouro = resposta['logradouro']
        bairro = resposta['bairro']
        print(resposta)
    except:
        resposta = ''
    
    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EmpresaForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Formulario enviado com sucesso!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cadastro-empresa/')
    else:
        if resposta != '':
            form = EmpresaForm(initial={
                'endereco': logradouro,
                'bairro': bairro
            })
            print(form)
        else:
            form = EmpresaForm()
        
    
    return render(request, 'cadastros/cadastro_empresa.html', locals())
```

esse é meu bloco que estou colocando o form.

```
{% block content %}
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header card-header-border-bottom">
                    <h2>Cadastro de Empresa</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% if form %}
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {{ form.cnpj|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {{ form.nome|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                        {{ form.ie|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                        {{ form.razao_social|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='form-row'>
                                    <div class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'>
                                        {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'>
                                        {{ form.fone|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class='form-row'>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
                                        {{ form.cep|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'>
                                        {{ form.cidade|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'>
                                        {{ form.uf|as_crispy_field }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {{ form.endereco|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {{ form.bairro|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {{ form.ativo|as_crispy_field }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ message }}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

esse é o jquery para chamar a url que chama a view lá em cima.

```
{% block script %}
    <script>
    $("#id_cep").blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'cadastro_empresa' %}",
            method: 'GET',
            data:{cep: $('#id_cep').val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#id_nome').val();
            },  
            success: function(response){
                
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
{% endblock  %}
```

e por fim esse é o retorno de quando dou print no meu form depois do "if resposta != ''"

```
<tr><th><label for="id_endereco">Endereco:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="endereco" value="Rua Nelson Cordeiro" maxlength="400" required id="id_endereco"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_bairro">Bairro:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="bairro" value="Loteamento Marinoni" maxlength="200" required id="id_bairro"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_cep">Cep:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="cep" maxlength="9" required id="id_cep"></td></tr>
```

como podem ver ele está enviando junto com o form as values com os valores da api que estou consultando mas infelizmente esses valores não são renderizados na tela alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que renderizar esse seu form no HTML. Primeiro, você vai ter que retornar essa variável `form` como um `json`. Esse trecho de código vai no lugar do `print(form)`. Assim:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
data = {}
data["form"] = form
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Em seguida, no javascript, dentro da função `success`, você vai pegar o retorno que vem na variável `response` e renderizar em alguma `div` vazia no html. Assim:

```
// coloquei o id div-vazia, mas você altera de acordo com a sua necessidade
$('#div-vazia').html(response.form);
```

Existe também outra forma, que seria jogando os valores diretamente nos inputs.

Esse trecho de código vai no lugar do `print(form)`.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
data = {}
data["endereco"] = logradouro
data["bairro"] = bairro
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Esse trecho de código vai dentro do `success`.

```
const endereco = response.endereco
const bairro = response.bairro
$("#id_endereco").val(endereco);
$("#id_bairro").val(bairro);
```

Resumindo, aqui retornamos `json` da `view`, recebemos essas informações na função `AJAX` e manipulamos o `DOM` para exibir essas informações. Vlw!